# scroll line to specific screen line

Tags: scrolling

I am search for the opposite of [winline()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#winline%28%29). `winline()` returns the screen line in the window of the current cursor position.
I want to be able to *set* it. Therefore scroll the windows content so that the line the cursor is currently in, lands in screen line x.

vim already provides commands like [zz](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#zz) to scroll the current line to the middle of the window or [zt](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#zt) to scroll it to the top of the window. But I didn't find a way to scroll it to a specific line.

*Edit*:

Just for reference: I can calculate it myself by getting the actual winline with `winline()`, calculating the difference and calling one of:

```
execute "normal! " . count . "\<C-Y>"
execute "normal! " . count . "\<C-E>"
```

But that seems slightyl awkward to me and has the actual drawback that it won't work (and in fact does unpredictable things) if the user remapped `<C-Y>` or `<C-E>` to some other operation.

Comment: "I want to be able to set it." If you want to move the cursor, use "nG" where n is the line number. For example "42G" moves to the forty-second line. https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#up-down-motions

Comment: `it won't work ... if the user remapped <C-Y> or <C-E>` Actually, you are using `normal!` (with the bang), which ignores mappings

Comment: @shawnhcorey No, I don't want to set the cursor to a different line. I want it to _stay_ on the current line, but that line be moved to a certain _screen line_ . Like `zt` moves the line with the cursor to the top of the window (while the cursor remains in that line).

Comment: @husB Yes! You are right, of course! So that workaround isn't too bad.