# Can you prevent then screen jumping when toggling the wrap option?

Tags: scrolling, wrap

When I enable the `wrap` option, the first line of the viewport remains fixed and the lines below it are all shunted down as they are wrapped. This means the cursor line jumps down too, which is distracting for my use case (I need to rapidly toggle between wrap and nowrap using a shortcut key).

Is there a way to prevent this, so that the viewport is anchored on the current line and any newly wrapped text above this is line is shunted up?

I found `winline()` which gives me the cursor row number in the viewport, but there is no corresponding `setwinline()` function. Furthermore, you can't just scroll up or down by the change in `winline()` because some of those lines may be wrapped.

Related: [scroll line to specific screen line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/scroll-line-to-specific-screen-line)

Comment: Does the solution you found work with [`'smoothscroll'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smoothscroll%27) set?

Comment: I'm using vim 8.2, so this option isn't available. Although I could upgrade myself, I'd like to support older versions as this feature is part of a plugin: https://github.com/rogerkeays/vimjournal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always possible to achieve the desired output since the first window row is always the start of a line (if `smoothscroll` is not set)

Suppose you have that text (with cursor at row 2):

```
 2 line 2 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
>3 line 3 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
 4 line 4 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
```

When you toggle wrap:

You can have (with cursor at row 3):

```
 2 line 2 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
>3 line 3 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
 4 line 4 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
```

or (with cursor at row 1):

```
>3 line 3 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
 4 line 4 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
```

But not (with cursor at row 2 as you which):

```
   foo bar tom foo
>3 line 3 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
 4 line 4 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
```

Another limitation is that the start of the text is always at row 1

Suppose you start with (cursor at row 6)

```
 2 line 2 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
 3 line 3 foo bar tom
   foo bar tom foo
 4 line 4 foo bar tom
>  foo bar tom foo
```

When you toggle wrap the best you can have is (with cursor at row 4):

```
 1 line 1 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
 2 line 2 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
 3 line 3 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
>4 line 4 foo bar tom foo bar tom foo
```

That being said here is an approximation of what you would like to have:

```
function GetWinWidth()
  let ret = winwidth(0)

  if &signcolumn !=# 'no'
    let ret = ret - 2
  endif

  if &number
    let ret = ret - max([&numberwidth, float2nr(log10(line('$'))) + 2])
  endif

  return ret
endfunction

function WrapRowDelta(line1, line2)
  " This is an approximation that could be improved :-)
  let ret = 0
  let max_width = GetWinWidth()
  for i in range(a:line1, a:line2 - 1)
    if foldclosed(i) < 0
      let ret = ret + float2nr(ceil(str2float(len(getline(i)) + 1) / max_width))
    elseif foldclosed(i) == i
      let ret = ret + 1
    endif
  endfor
  return ret
endfunction

function! NoWrapRowDelta(line1, line2)
  " return a:line2 - a:line1
  let ret = 0
  for i in range(a:line1, a:line2 - 1)
    if foldclosed(i) < 0
      let ret = ret + 1
    elseif foldclosed(i) == i
      let ret = ret + 1
    endif
  endfor
  return ret
endfunction

function! CorrectCursorScroll()
  if &wrap 
    " Estimation of the previous space:
    let nonwrap_row_delta = NoWrapRowDelta(line('w0'), line('.'))

    " Value of the current space
    let wrap_row_delta = screenpos(0, line('.'), col('.')).row - 1
    while wrap_row_delta > nonwrap_row_delta
      exe "normal! \<C-e>"
      let r = screenpos(0, line('.'), col('.')).row - 1
      if wrap_row_delta == r
        break
      endif
      let wrap_row_delta = r
    endwhile
    if wrap_row_delta < nonwrap_row_delta
      exe "normal! \<C-y>"
    endif
  else
    " Estimation of the previous space:
    let wrap_row_delta = WrapRowDelta(line('w0'), line('.'))

    " Value of the current space
    let nonwrap_row_delta = NoWrapRowDelta(line('w0'), line('.'))
    while wrap_row_delta > nonwrap_row_delta
      exe "normal! \<C-y>"
      let r = NoWrapRowDelta(line('w0'), line('.'))
      if nonwrap_row_delta == r
        break
      endif
      let nonwrap_row_delta = r
    endwhile
    if wrap_row_delta < nonwrap_row_delta
      exe "normal! \<C-e>"
    endif
  endif
endfunction

autocmd! OptionSet wrap call CorrectCursorScroll()
```

Comment: Hmm... this solution seems to have some problems with code folding. Maybe `winline()` can help?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If you could give me more information about the code folding problem you have I would see if I can improve it ;-)

Comment: I see indeed an obvious problem (I'll try to fix it when I have some time). I'll keep you posted :-)

Comment: When there is at least one visible closed fold above the cursor, the cursor line will keep moving down the viewport when you toggle wrap, until it hits the bottom. If there are closed folds below the cursor, or if the fold above is scrolled out of view it works fine.

Comment: I have provided a new version that should work better with fold. Let me know if it works for you :-)

Comment: Latest version is working pretty well. I'm getting some cases where the screen slips down one row each time. Hard to reproduce though. There also seems to be some sort of infinite loop when at the bottom of the screen and when invoking `:Explore`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If you give a way to reproduce I have a look :-)

Comment: I have provided a new version that should not have infinite loop.

Comment: This is working pretty well now, thanks. There are still some corner cases that cause slipping, but they'll have to wait until I get more time to investigate. Do you mind if I use this code for https://github.com/rogerkeays/vimjournal (MIT license)?

Comment: You are welcome to use it whenever you want :-)